# Command combines all the words in the .txt file

Tags: python, discord.py

**What I'm trying to do**: I'm learning how to use `append` and other file related things for my discord.py bot. This is to be used for code saving tags later on.

**Problem**: My text file is not organized the way I had expected it to, as shown in the images provided.
[image: Words don't separate] Words don't Separate

[image: Expectation] Expectation, as shown in multiple other tutorials and 'asks' I've looked through

```py
@client.command()
async def save(ctx, *, arg):
    fn = "texttag.txt"
    with open(fn, "a") as f:
        f.write(arg)
        await ctx.send(f"**{arg}** has been appended to `texttag.txt`")
        return
```

Comment: If you are using python3.6 or higher you can print a newline after each time you write to the file like so:
```f.write(f"{arg}\n"})``` now you will have each entry to your file written on a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a new line character after each string before writing it in file  like

```
string str = "abc" + "\n";
```

then write it. I hope it will solve the problem.